# Tmobile access point (FAST 5688W) with google Wifi mesh - together

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, mesh-networking

I'm trying to set up a network that combines the internet connection from a T-Mobile access point with the network hardware from Google WiFi pucks, and maintain the existing "myHome" network.

I would like to be able to unplug the T-Mobile access point and take it with me when traveling, but still keep the "myHome" network. Specifically, I'm looking for a solution that does not require me to change the configuration of the T-Mobile access point to put it back into broadcast mode. Any ideas?

Comment: myHome is the wi-fi name (SSID) of the Google Wi-Fi routers? I mean you could just use an ethernet cord to plug the Google Wi-Fi puck into the tmobile access point. Then when you bring the access point with you the google wi-fi network still works, just no internet access. This DOES cause two different wi-fi names & for them to overlap making connections possibly slower. However you said you didn't want to change t-mobile access point config so that it what it is

Comment: Well. It works well. Really just a connection from the t mobile ap to the mesh network.

Have both ssids and it works great. I wish I understood this better. Where is the dhcp and how do I get the ip addresses.

Comment: I've copied my comment to an answer since you seem to imply it fixed your issue, please upvote or accept as answer whichever you deem

Answer (score 1):

myHome is the wi-fi name (SSID) of the Google Wi-Fi routers? I mean you could just use an ethernet cord to plug the Google Wi-Fi puck into the tmobile access point. Then when you bring the access point with you the google wi-fi network still works, just no internet access. This DOES cause two different wi-fi names & for them to overlap making connections possibly slower. However you said you didn't want to change t-mobile access point config so that it what it is

As for how you wanting to understand it better, specifically DHCP, & get IP address (likely to the router interfaces/webconfig):

`ipconfig` or similar command if you use Linux/Mac can get you the gateway IP address which should be the router you are connected to. Technically you have a double-NAT ([Network Address Translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation), [cisco explanation](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/routers/network-address-translation.html)) which I don't 100% understand. Basically means you have two different networks as both tmobile & google likely are offering DHCP. I can try to explain further, but you may be better suited at trying that command, reading links I gave, or doing general google search.